# social network FB,Twitter, G+ etc.. in all 3 platforms (iOS , Android and Blackberry)

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, social-networking

I have came across some open source tool like pinklestar, sharekit for social integration in Android and iOS.

Is there any tool/API/framework available for all 3 platforms ( blackberry also) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, these are all 3 separate platforms and 3 separate questions, possibly 9 individual questions (3 questions for each platform)

facebook and twitter both use oAuth so thats a start, G+ just got an api out but I'm not sure if thats complete yet - check back daily